# Full Calendar adding images in the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to add additional icons on the date , For example on the calendar June 01 I can add an icon like a wine symbol on the said date instead of color. I tried to the following code but it wont work.

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready()

        $(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    events: [
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2018-06-01',
      imageurl:'http://www.completecocktails.com/img/d/l/ShotInTheDark.png'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2018-06-05',
      end    : '2018-06-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2018-06-09T12:30:00',
      allDay : false // will make the time show

    }
  ]
   eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    if (event.imageurl) {
        eventElement.prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl +"' width='12' height='12'>");
    }
},
```

Comment: your code is incomplete. Please post the full code

Comment: I can't reproduce the error it seems to be working ok http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/2302/

Comment: that is weird it wasn't working before I slept.  the page won't appear

Comment: your code adds icons to the event, not the date (i.e. the day itself). Is that what you wanted? And yes according to StaticBeagle's JSFiddle it works perfectly at what it does.

Comment: Yes, I saw the error i missed "{" after the document.ready function apologies....

Comment: you don't need `$(document).ready()` _and_

        `$(function() {` - they are both the same thing, just using different syntaxes (one is a shortcut). Choose one and stick to it, and remove the other one (and its closing bracket, obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In events you just need to add

```
imageurl:'https://images/images.png',

and add this 
    eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
      if (event.imageurl) {
        eventElement.prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl + "' width='80' height='80' >");
      }  return ['all', event.tags].indexOf($('#event_selector option:selected').val()) >= 0;



    },
```